# next js empty render when i import data

Tags: next.js

my problem is when i want to fetch data from data.json nothing display it give me many empty array when i try to console.log
screenshot:
[screenshot and path of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK6Iw.png)
i tried hard to change the import path to back with ../ but nothing display to me im so wonder about this error and this is my first time i work with next js

```
import Image from 'next/image'

const  EventPerCityPage = ({data}) => {
  console.log("helloa"+data)
    return (
      <div>
       <h1> event in london</h1>
       <div>
        {data.map((ev)=>{
          <a key={ev.id} href={`/events/${ev.city}/${ev.id}`}>
             <Image width={300} height={300} alt={ev.title} src={ev.image} /> 
             <h2>{ev.title}</h2>
        <p>{ev.description}</p>
        
          </a>
        })}
       
       </div>
       <p>hello</p>
      </div>
      
    )
  }
  export default EventPerCityPage;

  export async function getStaticPaths (){
    const {events_categories} = await import ('/data/data.json')
    console.log(events_categories+"this code")
    const allPaths = events_categories.map(ev=>{
      return{
        
          params: {
            cat: ev.id.toString()
          }
        
      }
    })
    console.log(allPaths)
    return{
      paths: allPaths,
      fallback:false
    }
  }
  export async function getStaticProps(context){
    
    const id = context?.params.cat
    console.log("all path aaaaaaaa" +id)
    const {allEvents} = await import('/data/data.json')
    console.log(allEvents+"rrrrrrtttttttt")//
    const data = allEvents.filter((ev) => ev.city===id)
    console.log(data+"eeeeeeeeeezzzzzzz")
    return{
      props: {data} 
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include a return.

```js
<div>
    {data.map((ev) => {
        return (
            <a key={ev.id} href={`/events/${ev.city}/${ev.id}`}>
                <Image width={300} height={300} alt={ev.title} src={ev.image} /> 
                <h2>{ev.title}</h2>
                <p>{ev.description}</p>
            </a>
        )
     })}
```